# Backbone model toJSON does not render all attributes

Tags: javascript, sql, json, backbone.js

I've found questions like this: [Backbone model .toJSON() doesn't render all attributes to JSON by model.set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330533/backbone-model-tojson-doesnt-render-all-attributes-to-json-by-model-set)

But they were not solved.

I have a similar problem. Here's a sample code:

```
Animal = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    ...,
    initStats:function(){
        this.attributes.stats = [];
        var that = this;
        var type = new Species();
        type.store.findAll(type, function(tx, res){
            var base = JSON.parse(res.rows.item(that.attributes.did-1).value);
            that.set("name",base.name);
            that.set("text", base.text);
            return that;
        }, function(tx,err){console.log(err)}, "");
    }
});
```

`type.store.findAll` is a function in Species class that connects to DB and return all species.

And on another page I do:

```
mym = new Animal();
    mym.initStats().save(); //see below
    mym.store.findAll(mym, function(tx,res){
        for(var i = 0;i < res.rows.length; i++){
            console.log(res.rows.item(i).value);
        }
    }, function(tx,err){console.log(err)}, "");
```

Again, `Animal.store.findAll` is a function to find all animals. `Animal.save()` has its SQL generation function as follows:

```
create: function (model,success,error,options) {
        //when you want use your id as identifier, use apiid attribute
        if(!model.attributes[model.idAttribute]) {
            // Reference model.attributes.apiid for backward compatibility.
            var obj = {};

            if(model.attributes.apiid){
                obj[model.idAttribute] = model.attributes.apiid;
                delete model.attributes.apiid;
            }else{
                obj[model.idAttribute] = guid();
            }            
            model.set(obj);
        }

        var colNames = ["`id`", "`value`"];
        var placeholders = ['?', '?'];
        var params = [model.attributes[model.idAttribute], JSON.stringify(model.toJSON())];
                    console.log(model);
                    console.log(model.toJSON());
        this.columns.forEach(function(col) {
            colNames.push("`" + col.name + "`");
            placeholders.push(['?']);
            params.push(model.attributes[col.name]);
        });
        var orReplace = WebSQLStore.insertOrReplace ? ' OR REPLACE' : '';
                    //console.log("INSERT" + orReplace + " INTO `" + this.tableName + "`(" + colNames.join(",") + ")VALUES(" + placeholders.join(",") + ");");
        this._executeSql("INSERT" + orReplace + " INTO `" + this.tableName + "`(" + colNames.join(",") + ")VALUES(" + placeholders.join(",") + ");", params, success, error, options);
```

console outputs are:(I'll just put stringified JSON)

> s {cid: "c575", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
>   `{"name":null, "text":null, "id":"5475b1e0-9d6c-48d1-e090-cb84e4e84ca6"}` 
>   `{"name":null, "text":null, "id":"5475b1e0-9d6c-48d1-e090-cb84e4e84ca6"}`

id is generated by other functions in the model. The first line is the model(before toJSON), the second line is a JSON object, the third line is SQL select result. Three lines in actual printout order.

I don't know why the name and text are null. In the console output, they all have value under s.attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the findAll function is asynchronous, how do you know that the save() in `mym.initStats().save();` isn't happening *before* the findAll within initStats has completed?

Comment: save() calls the create() function, in which I let the console logs the model and the JSON string at the same time. The model has the attributes set in initStats(), but the JSON string does not. So I do think findAll() happened before save(), but something messed up when the model was converted to JSON. After all, save() is called from findAll(); @erturne